# Program to send text between 2 computers on the internet without intermediate server

Tags: python, networking, p2p

I want  a python class/module/library that can connect 2 computers(say clientA and clientB) on the internet and send a string messages between clientA to ClientB.
I don't mind providing ip addresses/ports or whatever in required within the program of clientA and clientB. The string to be transmitted can also for now be hardcoded into one of the clients. aka. I do not need a UI at the moment to enter the string. The sent string can also be seen on the terminal for now. However, the following are the restrictions

1. I should be able to do this over any regular network connected to the internet. For instance from a computer in my home connected via Wifi to the router and then the internet. Same for the client on the other end
2. No changes to the network should be done as I want to be able to take this program on my computer to any network
3. No intermediate computer/server is needed. To elaborate the same clientA and clientB should just be connected to the internet and any message should not be sent to an intermediate server.

I know that peer-to-peer networks like torrents etc do this with files. but have not been able to figure out how a computer in a subnet like 192.168.x.x can be uniquely identified on the internet.

The rough template can be like:

```
class Client:
    def __init__(self):
        self.ipaddress="xxxx"
        self.port="yyyy"
        self.otherConfig1="aaaa"
        self.otherConfig2="bbbb"

    def messageReceived(message:str):
        print(f"The message is {message}")


    def messageSend(message:str):
        #hardcoded identifier/ipaddress etc of other client
        #code to send the message to that identifier

    def main():
        #infinite loop
        #send a string message every 10 seconds(for testing)
        # keep checking if as message is received

     if __name__== "__main__" :
          main()
```

Comment: Every hole piercing technology requires at least a freely reachable seed or metadata server freely to work under all NAT conditions.

Comment: If we can come with some way to communicate meta data to the clients then what would be the code?

Comment: Don't expect me to write a full NAT hole piercing framework for you. This is like the largest problem in creating P2P networks.

Comment: Surely there is got to be some standard libraries written for this work, considering this seems to be such a general issue. It would be great to get details of such libraries.